# How to Create Multiple shipment programmatically in magento 2

Tags: magento2, programmatically, shipment

If user added 2 different product in order, want to create two shipment on ready for dispatch button , programmatically .

Comment: These two shipments would be sent to the same address?

Comment: yes , it would be sent to same address